# Radio Button change detection SVG animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I need to run an svg animation when a user selects a corresponding radio button; the reference being the value of the radio button equating to the id of the animation. Here is a diluted example of what needs to happen.

If the user clicks a radio button, all radio buttons with that name need to either have a green or blue background: blue if it is the checked button, and green if it is not.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change( function(){

    var $scribbleSelectorName = $(this).attr('name');
    var $scribbleSelectorInputs = $("input[name=" + $scribbleSelectorName + "]");

    $($scribbleSelectorInputs).each(function(){


        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(this).css("background","green");
        }

        else {
            $(this).css("background","blue");
        }

    });

});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariahw1190/gfpj3qsx/). I have looked through many similar issues, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Hi Mariah.  Please provide a working sample. The preferred method here is to use a [code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have updated the question and included a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your backgrounds work, but are invisible. I changed to highlight parent element, which is `<li>`.

```
$(this).parent().css("background","green");
```

I also changed `$(this).attr("checked")` to `$(this).prop("checked")`.

About second part of your question, you can load an animation like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change( function(){
    var $scribbleSelectorName = $(this).attr('name');
    var $scribbleSelectorValue = $(this).attr('value');
    var $image = $('<img/>', {
        'src': imagesMap[$scribbleSelectorName][$scribbleSelectorValue]
    });
    $('.svg-container.' + $scribbleSelectorName).empty().append($image);
});

var imagesMap = {
    test: {
        'A': 'http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/acid.svg',
        'B': 'http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/adobe.svg',
        'C': 'http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/alphachannel.svg',
        'D': 'http://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg'
    },
    anotherGroupOfInputs: {
        //...
    }
};
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/gfpj3qsx/2/

Comment: Hey @mkutyba you did get the fiddle to work, but for some reason this is still not solving my problem. the HTML for each of the inputs and their corresponding SVG is like this https://jsfiddle.net/mariahw1190/2gudqwr3/ with the SVG within the same figure. I tried to alter your fiddle to select the child SVG element of the parent to animate, but I am still getting nowhere :[

Comment: How is it supposed to animate? It is a static path.

Comment: The SVG is just a path and the stroke-dashoffset is the attribute being animated. I updated the fiddle to include the script that i was using to animate it https://jsfiddle.net/mariahw1190/2gudqwr3/4/ . Right now the animations are running correctly if the related input has been selected, but the SVG dashoffset is not reseting if another input with the same name has been selected.

Comment: Don't put event handler inside antoher event handler (`.change` inside of `.change`), it won't work as you expect.

Comment: Well I think your script is cleaner and being more dependable so ignore what I had, so I am planning on wiping that out completely. However, your script is not allowing me to select the corresponding SVG element.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with SVGs so I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93262/discussion-between-mariah-weathersby-and-mkutyba).